# Angular $broadcast not working on local content?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, broadcast

I have an app running local on a device, app and all content needed is stored locally.

My problem simplified is this :)

```
In a service :
$rootScope.$broadcast('Weather.update', somevalue);

In Controller :
$scope.$on('Weather.update', function (event, temp) {
// weather has been updated
$scope.temperature = temp + '°';
})
```

*This is working fine with a webserver running, but fails when started without.*

**So my question : Do $broadcast only work if application is not running locally?**

Additional info:
If I make a setup with $watch in controller, listening at a function in service, that works fine, but I'm trying to avoid that solution, because $watch seems to run as a neverending listening loop that puts on a load on cpu (which is an issue in my case), so a solution where I can notify when needed, instead of constant listening, seems to be a better solution for me.

Comment: How are you running the app locally?

Comment: It should work locally. $broadcast is used by angular core the whole time (for example when you change route it fires of a bunch of broadcasts like '$routeChaneSuccess'. Could it be some issue with your local machine not retrieving the 'somevalue' for the weather update?

Comment: @Atropo I use localpath to index.html in Chrome

Comment: @mylescc I will make a restart and see if it makes a difference and test on another machine - I'll let U know

Comment: @mylescc Seems like a computer reboot was all it took to make $broadcast to start firing again, strange world these bits and bytes, but anyway, thank U both for taking time. Cheers

Comment: @HippieSvin Great! glad its working.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Chrome, try to launch it with the option: `--allow-file-access-from-files` and then open your application locally.

Answer (score 0):

**Do $broadcast also work if application is running locally?**
Yes it does, if not, try rebooting, worked for me :)